# How to check if server is sending out spam?

Tags: smtp, ip, spam, plesk, blacklist

I checked my IP address today because I was getting bounced back emails and I see it has been blacklisted on a few lists.  I only use my website to send out customer emails and no newsletter emails; so I don't send many emails out.

I don't know why my dedicated IP address would be blacklisted; is there a way to check my server running Plesk to see if someone is using my IP address to spam?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

prints destination of all email which sent from your server:

```
 cat  /var/log/maillog | grep  'to=<[a-z0-9_\.-]\+@[\da-z\.-]\+\.[a-z\.]\{2,6\}>' -o
```

Comment: file could be `/var/log/mail.log` as per my system

Answer (score 0):

Check the outgoing logs on your mail server to see if there are messages in there that you don't recognize.

Comment: How to parse the maillog in var/log ?